# Audio from left speaker then from right speaker

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I want a beep to be played from right speaker, after some time from left speaker. so sound should zigzag in between left/right speakers.

I have found this [link](http://www.codebase.es/riffwave/) but I don't know how to work with mp3 while using this.

Answer (score 0):

hey man on the link you provided: 
There four types of sound systems:

**Noise, Sine wave ,Effect, Stereo**

So , when you play with stero you can manage to play the sound on the left and the right by turning one after ,another.

Its the same as LR stereo(both) so , look that code man , while you make it stereo play some other sound on the left/right .

the complete code to do that is :

```
<script>

// STEREO
var wave4 = new RIFFWAVE();
wave4.header.sampleRate = 22000;
wave4.header.numChannels = 2;
wave4.header.bitsPerSample = 16;
var i = 0;
var stereo = [];
while (i<100000) {
  stereo[i++] = 0;
  stereo[i++] = 0x8000+Math.round(0x7fff*Math.sin(i/25));
}
while (i<200000) {
  stereo[i++] = 0x8000+Math.round(0x7fff*Math.sin(i/100));
  stereo[i++] = 0;
}
wave4.Make(stereo);
var audio4 = new Audio(wave4.dataURI);

function play(audio) {
  if (!audio.paused) { // if playing stop and rewind
    audio.pause();
    audio.currentTime = 0;
  }
  audio.play();
}

</script>
```

The Key code is here : **wave4.header.numChannels = 2;** . see change the channel to 1 or 0 or some other value and experiment on stereo code.

Also , there is a live data URI generator [here](http://dopiaza.org/tools/datauri/index.php) 
Cheers!

Comment: Thankyou Daniel, but problem i am facing is to deal with mp3 sound, can i convert mp3 sound to dataURI somehow?

Comment: One more question, i have got my mp3 converted to data URI which is large, very large. my question is, am i have to write this in array or string? i have tried as string but failed. what do you suggest?